# SQL query to calculate summation of row with previous row along with missing rows

Tags: sql-server

This is my table

```
Month  Year     count of subscription per date
----   ----   ----------------------------

1     2010         10
2     2010         30
4     2010         20 
7     2010         40
2     2011         60
```

Please need your help, I need to get the result like below table, summation second row with first row, same thing for another rows: Here some months are missed in above table got added with 0 as count of subscription column

```
Month  Year     count of subscription per date      sum of subscription
----   ---       ----------------------------       ---------------------

1     2010         10                                 10
2     2010         30                                 40
3     2010         0                                  40
4     2010         20                                 60
5     2010         0                                  60 
6     2010         0                                  60
7     2010         40                                 100
8     2010         0                                  100
9     2010         0                                  100
10    2010         0                                  100
11    2010         0                                  100
12    2010         0                                  100
 1    2011         0                                  100
 2    2011         60                                 160
 3    2011         0                                  160
```

and so on till

```
 12    2011        0                                  160
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this way**

```
create table #temp
    (
     [Month]  int,
     [year] int,
     [count of subscription per date] int,
     [sum of] int

    )

    declare @id int,@sumall int
    set @id=1
    set @sumall=0
    while(@id<=12)
    begin 
    if exists(select month from [your table] where month=@id)
    begin
    set @sumall=@sumall+(select count  from [your table] where month=@id)
    insert into #temp
    select month,year,count,@sumall as summ from [your table] where month=@id
    end

    else
    begin
    insert into #temp
    select @id,'2010',0,@sumall 
    end
    set @id=@id+1
    end
    select * from #temp
```